# will android emulator access a network using a vpn on the host machine

Tags: android, android-emulator

My Android app uses a web service that can only be accessed from the office network. I would like to debug at home. 
I can VPN into my office network with ssh on a MAC or putty in windows. Will the Android emulator "automatically" access the office network under VPN or do it requires a specific set-up?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem to be working for me automatically, no.  I'm emulating Google API Level 9 in Windows 7 64-bit, and I can't access pages in the Android browser that I can access on my host machine when my host machine is on my company VPN.  I can access other sites like google.com in the emulator, so it does have network access.