# How to enable VPN support in Android Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-2.2-froyo

I like to use a PPTP VPN in the Android emulator. My VPN provider is Witopia. The settings work on a real phone (HTC Desire).

It does not work, the connection just times out after a while.

**adb logcat** prints:

```
D/VpnManager( 1527): succeeded to connect to VPN service
D/com.android.settings.vpn.AuthenticationActor( 1527): ~~~~~~ connect() succeeded!
I/SProxy_mtpd( 2211): Stop VPN daemon: mtpd
D/VpnSettings( 1527): received connectivity: Witopia: connected? CONNECTING   err=0
D/SProxy_mtpd( 2211): mtpd is stopped after 0 msec
D/SProxy_mtpd( 2211): stopping mtpd, success? true
I/SProxy_racoon( 2211): Stop VPN daemon: racoon
D/SProxy_racoon( 2211): racoon is stopped after 0 msec
D/SProxy_racoon( 2211): stopping racoon, success? true
D/VpnService( 2211):   Local IP: 10.0.2.15, if: eth0
D/VpnService( 2211):        VPN UP: down
I/SProxy_mtpd( 2211): Start VPN daemon: mtpd
D/SProxy_mtpd( 2211): mtpd is running after 0 msec
D/SProxy_mtpd( 2211): service not yet listen()ing; try again
D/mtpd    ( 2224): Waiting for control socket
D/mtpd    ( 2224): Received 19 arguments
I/mtpd    ( 2224): Using protocol pptp
I/mtpd    ( 2224): Connecting to 203.131.247.213 port 1723
I/SProxy_mtpd( 2211): got data from control socket: 19
I/mtpd    ( 2224): Connection established (socket = 10)
D/mtpd    ( 2224): Sending SCCRQ
D/mtpd    ( 2224): Received SCCRP -> Sending OCRQ (local = 32087)
I/mtpd    ( 2224): Tunnel established
D/mtpd    ( 2224): Received OCRQ (remote = 52286)
I/mtpd    ( 2224): Session established
I/mtpd    ( 2224): Creating PPPoX socket
F/mtpd    ( 2224): Socket() Address family not supported by protocol
```

Followed by the user message: **Unable to connect to the network. Do you want to try again?**

Meanwhile in **adb logcat**

```
E/VpnService( 2211): onError()
E/VpnService( 2211): java.io.IOException: Connecting timed out
E/VpnService( 2211):    at com.android.server.vpn.VpnService.waitUntilConnectedOrTimedout(VpnService.java:206)
E/VpnService( 2211):    at com.android.server.vpn.VpnService.onConnect(VpnService.java:136)
E/VpnService( 2211):    at com.android.server.vpn.VpnServiceBinder$2.run(VpnServiceBinder.java:114)
E/VpnService( 2211):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
I/VpnService( 2211): disconnecting VPN...
D/VpnSettings( 1527): received connectivity: Witopia: connected? DISCONNECTING   err=0
I/SProxy_mtpd( 2211): Stop VPN daemon: mtpd
D/SProxy_mtpd( 2211): mtpd is stopped after 0 msec
D/SProxy_mtpd( 2211): stopping mtpd, success? true
I/SProxy_racoon( 2211): Stop VPN daemon: racoon
D/SProxy_racoon( 2211): racoon is stopped after 0 msec
D/SProxy_racoon( 2211): stopping racoon, success? true
D/VpnService( 2211): onFinalCleanUp()
I/VpnService( 2211): restore original suffices --> null
D/VpnSettings( 1527): received connectivity: Witopia: connected? IDLE   err=101
```

I guess this is either a permission problem or the Android emulator does not support it.

My platform is MacOSX, Emulator is running Android 2.2.

This question is related to:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3223344/does-vpn-in-the-android-emulator-2-2-work
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442865/setting-up-a-vpn-in-the-emulator
- [will android emulator access a network using a vpn on the host machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3859675/will-android-emulator-access-a-network-using-a-vpn-on-the-host-machine)

Comment: I bought another device (a iRobot tablet) and tried the VPN there. Same message regarding `Address family not supported by protocol`. So this might be a kernel issue?

Comment: check these lines...com.android.server.vpn.VpnService.onConnect(VpnService.java:136)
E/VpnService( 2211):    at com.android.server.vpn.VpnServiceBinder$2.run(VpnServiceBinder.java:114)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes it is like kernal issue:

1. No tun.ko module (see http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=630703&page=2)
2. No support lkm (loadable kernel module) (http://code.google.com/p/get-a-robot-vpnc/issues/detail?id=100)

So I think you need custom kernel
http://code.google.com/p/batterymine/wiki/BuildingInModuleSupport

Also you will need copy to emulator other modules: slhc.ko, ppp*.ko

Comment: I think that's it, didn't know it's possible to install custom kernels in the emulator! Thanks a lot, sibnick!

Comment: @Sebastian Roth: Can you please tell me exactly which kernal is required by emulator? I checked this link ttp://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=630703&page=2, but its procedure is for Nexsus one, will it be the same for emulator, where can I get tun.ko,slhc.ko, ppp*.ko for emulator (API level 15). Do I need some other modules too?!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with a 2.2 emulator.  I switched to a 4.2 emulator and it is working fine through the VPN.